# How to copy one element of a generic collection

Tags: c#

I need to copy one element of a generic collection and add it to the list. Something similar to this:

```
private List<CalculationResult> cantileverResults = new List<CalculationResult>();
cantileverResults.Add(cantileverResults[previousIndex]);
```

The problem with this solution is that when I modify the new element, the previousIndex element changes as well. I believe this is because they are reference-type, not value-type. How can I just copy (clone?) the information from one element to another without affecting each other any further?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a `new` object when adding it.

This can be done in several ways - a helper method that takes an object of your type (`CalculationResult`) and returns a completely new one.

Perhaps have a constructor overload that does this.

There are many ways to achieve such a thing - implementing [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) and having the `Clone` method return a new object.

For example, if you were to create a constructor overload, this is how you could use it:

```
cantileverResults.Add(new CalculationResult(cantileverResults[previousIndex]));
```